# Using Browser Imports with webpack

Tags: node.js, webpack, import, module, webpack-4

I am using webpack to compile a plugin for a shopify theme that leverages browser based modules `<script type ='module'...></script>` allowing you to import universal functionality with `import {Drawer} from '/theme.js'` this works great except that I am not including the `theme.js` in my webpack so I get errors:

```
ERROR in external "/theme.js"
The target environment doesn't support dynamic import() syntax so it's not possible to use external type 'module' within a script
```

### Solution 1

Using a dynamic import with `webpackIgnore:true` seems to work like so:

```
import(/* webpackIgnore: true */ "/theme.js").then(() => {
...
});
```

but this is not ideal as there are other utilities and things that we'd like to import in other places in the code where we can't use dynamic imports.

### Solution 2

I tried using the `IgnorePlugin` to match the browser imports

```
new IgnorePlugin({
          resourceRegExp: /^\/theme.js$/
      })
```

which works to remove the initial error but still has a runtime error of:

```
Error: Cannot find module "theme.js"
```

Is there a better way to mix webpack with browser modules or is this just not the right approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the key is to use `externalsType: 'module'` along with `experiments.outputModule` so my final webpack config has this in it:

```
...
    experiments: {
      outputModule: true,
    },
    externalsType: 'module',
    externals: {
        'static.theme.js': 'https://cdn.shopify.com/.../static.theme.js'
    },
...
```